# React react-select / Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I use `react-select`
I get nex warning from react
`Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`

My component:

```
import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

import styles from "./Filter.module.scss";

interface SearchBarProps {
  setParametr: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
  data: Array<{ name: string; value: number }>;
  placeholder: string;
}

export const SearchBar: React.FC<SearchBarProps> = (props) => {
  // const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);

  const changeValue = (event: { name: string; value: number } | null) => {
    props.setParametr(event?.name || "");
  };

  return (
    <Select
      className={styles.input}
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      onChange={(event) => changeValue(event)}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => {
        return option.name;
      }}
      getOptionValue={(option) => {
        return option.value.toString();
      }}
      options={props.data}
    />
  );
};
```

I think the problem is related to the dropdown list, but I don't know how to set the key value for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your data has some repeating `value` entries. The `react-select` library uses `value` as keys for the options, so they need to be unique.

Comment: I looked - each component has a unique value. I use data from `https://guap-raspisanie.duckdns.org/api/v1/params`

Comment: @DenisDryagin make sure you're processing this data correctly. You can collect all values you're using as `value` and then run `console.log(new Set(values).size, values.length)` and check if they are the same.